# Auto increment primary key when using saveToCassandra()

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Is it possible to create auto increment primary key in table Cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cannot generate an auto-increment key in Cassandra. It doesn't really make sense in a distributed db, since some central point would need to be responsible for keeping the sequence.

A common way to make keys is to generate a UUID, which is random but almost impossible to create collision.

From wikipedia:

> for there to be a one in a billion chance of duplication, 103 trillion version 4 UUIDs must be generated.

If you are really, really worried about collision, then you can insert the new UUID using a "IF NOT EXISTS" [lightweight transaction](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertLWT.html)

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO mytable (uuid, text) VALUES (123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000, "hello") IF NOT EXISTS
```

Comment: it is possible to create table cassandra without primary key , thanks for your answer

Comment: its not possible. Cassandra needs a primary key to create a partition. If you don't have a primary key then just use a random UUID